# Debugging Surface RT 8.1 from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, arm, remote-debugging, windows-8.1

It seems only the VS 2013 Remote tools for ARM works on Windows 8.1.

Does this mean that Visual Studio 2012 is obsolete now for WinRT development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's indeed obsolete.

For windows 8.1 RT development, set up a separate 8.1 machine with VS 2013.

### Update

As of Visual Studio 2012 **Update 4**, remote debugging to 8.1 seems to be available.

Answer (score 2):

Update on 25 Nov 2013:

Just saw Moche's answer and was about to post the update. Yes VSE2012 on Win8.0 can now remote debug on Surface2 / Win8.1 using VS2012 Update 4 which was released over the weekend.

Also it is required to download the Remote Tools for Arm that are part of the Update 4:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=39305
Click the 'details drill down' to get the 'Remote Tools' Download

To get remote debugging running, you need to right-click on the project file in Solution Explorer and select debugging under the Configuration tab - then you will notice a field with 'machine name'... complete the machine name of the Surface 2 and select Authentication 'Yes' - Ensure both the Visual Studio Computer and Surface 2 are on the Same Workgroup in Control Panel, System, Advanced System Settings, Computer Name Tab. These brief instruction assume you will be using Windows Private lan authentication. If you want to use your live account for authentication simply google how to Remote Debug Visual Studio 2012 with Windows Live Authentication..

When you run the remote tools installation for the first time on the Surface 2 tablet, you will be prompted by a wizard which sets up the necessary exceptions for the Windows firewall on the tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I succeeded to do the debugging on 8.1 using VS2012. I've installed the latest update 4 of the Debugging Tools. Then I went in Windows Explorer to Program Files->MS Visual Studio 11->Common 7->IDE->Remote Debugger>arm and ran msvsmon from there. That's it - I was able to connect to it from my Windows 8 machine running VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer above that 'Its obsolete' pertaining to VS 2012 and debugging on Win 8.1 is (entirely) not correct - the correct phrase would be that Debugging on Win 8.1 client from a Visual Studio 2012 machine is not supported at time of Win 8.1 preview - Hopefully VS 2012 update will soon allow it to connect to Visual Studio 2013 remote debugger tools to allow Windows 8 development to continue between Windows 8 and Windows 8.1..

As Per:
http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2013/07/10/visual-studio-2012-2013-and-windows-8-1-apps-clarifications.aspx
Quoting:
Visual Studio 2012 (running on either Windows 8 or Windows 8.1) continues to support creating and working with Windows Store apps for Windows 8.  It does not support creating or working with Windows Store apps for Windows 8.1.  Apps targeting Windows 8 continue to work on Windows 8.1, they just can’t take advantage of all of the new Windows 8.1 functionality and performance improvements.

When I read the Answer above I got my knickers in a real twist and then I thankfully found this (and now have hope my shiny Surface 2 isn't a desk weight for developing) -->

quoting off:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e5bd281-4dde-418b-a9fe-078815523fe1/win-81-surface-remote-debugger

For debugging applications on Windows 8.1 Preview RT devices you need to use VS2013 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate Preview with the Remote Tools for VS2013 Preview.
We are aware that VS2012 is not compatible with Windows 8.1 Preview, and we are working to address this with the next update to VS2012.

Thanks,
Dave Lubash
Visual Studio Team

Comment: Where does it say 8.1 "Preview"? I can't find the word preview on my machine. I was under the impression I installed the final product.

Comment: For developing store apps on VS2013, windows 8.1 is required (as noted by the installer).

Answer (score 0):

@Carl L - After further digging.. It seems both our answers are sort of right.. To support Win 8.1 currently, you need Win 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 installed - I tried Installing Visual Studio 2013 Express on my Windows 8 PC and NO DICE..

I guess the only clarification I am adding is that developers can continue using Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012 to create apps that run on Windows 8 (only) and will also be available in the Apps Store and run compatibly on Windows 8.1 (but not use all the latest 8.1 optimized features). I am only taking this based on MS forum posts.. The information from Microsoft doesn't properly address this point in its documentation at:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility-2013

Its also worth pointing out that Visual Studio 2013 Express (free version) is not able to produce Windows 8 Apps - ONLY Windows 8.1 apps (so that part of your answer is correct currently). So in a sense it is unsafe to say Visual Studio 2012 is obsolete as it is currently required to support creation of Windows 8.0 apps.. Unless you don't mind ditching App updates for your existing user-base who may not have yet made the jump to 8.1 (not a sound development model and I am very surprised MS is making fragmentation on its own new platforms for developers currently).

At the moment I am a bit miffed that I am forced to upgrade to Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 in order to debug on my Surface 2 (RT) tablet and in that case would not be able to debug Windows 8.0 apps on my Surface 2 (RT) using VS 2012 until MS hopefully updates VS 2012 and/or the VS 2012 remote debugger tools.

Hope that clarifies a bit - seems you were mostly right which is a real shame if Microsoft is serious about attracting developers to its newest OS and having its free development tools rival that of Android OS and iOS..

Comment: can you stop posting so many answers to a question? Just edit whatever answer you have posted when you want to change something

Comment: Will do thumbmunkeys. An SO noob here.. In Future I will edit the one answer I give... thanks