# how can I remove Visual Studio 2012 Remote Debugging tools from Surface RT 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1, windows-rt

It appears that it's no longer possible to debug using VS2012 tools on a Surface RT running 8.1 (see [Debugging Surface RT 8.1 from Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489507/debugging-surface-rt-8-1-from-visual-studio-2012)).

So, how can I uninstall it, because it still has icons on the start menu, and items under program files.  The digital signature is no longer recognized, so it's not possible to uninstall via the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the program files folder of Visual Studio 11.
Then go to your registry keys in HKLM => Software => Microsoft and remove the Remote Debugger entry.

Now you can do a fresh install of the VS2013 remote debugger tools and next time you'll restart the old icon seems to be removed from the all apps screen.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah good luck with that, we will all need it... As is mentioned in a few places on the web, Win 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 can develop apps ONLY for Windows 8.1, while Windows 8.0 and Visual Studio 2012 can develop apps ONLY for Windows 8.0... You can install both side-by-side on the same machine (VS 2012 and VS 2013) though.

But what really gets me is that my new surface 2 is now a paperweight because I can no longer debug on it as I don't wish to abandon Windows 8.0 development ATM. I hope Microsoft addresses this as it could become a serious fragmentation issue and keep developers away in droves.

Comment: Not an answer. Just complaining.

Comment: Not a complaint. A valid criticism. The only way for a developer to publish an app with maximum Windows Store market reach is by publishing as Windows Store 8.0. As Windows Store 8.0 Apps are available on the Surface 2, its only reasonable to expect developers to have a way to test their code on the Surface 2 (using the free IDE tools as with other mobile platforms). I mentioned the update which fixed this if you follow the link in the question above. I am not sure why the downvote as I contributed clarity by spending hours reading MS documentation and sharing that here... sheesh...